# Change content of a HTML file by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

We all know that in PHP by using PHP's `file_put_contents(file, data, mode, context)` function we can change the contents of another file.

Does JavaScript have similar function? I mean can I change contents of a file by using JavaScript?

I have

```
                <?php

                $temp= file_get_contents('./inc/announcement.html');
                require_once(FACULTY180_CLASS_ROOT.'TinyMCEMaker.php');
                $richtext = new TinyMCEMaker('basic');
                $richtext->editor('Description', $temp);
                ?>

                <script>
                function get_editor_content() {

                      //method1 getting the content of the active editor
                      var a = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();


                    }
                </script>
                <button onclick="get_editor_content()">Save</button>
```

So when Save button is clicked I have to update contents of the "announcement.html" file? varible "a" contains the new data that has to be wriitten to the html file.

I found the answer and it works:

```
  <form action="Home.php" method="post" id="announcement">

<?php

$temp= file_get_contents('./path to html file');
require_once(the_class_name.'TinyMCEMaker.php');
$richtext = new TinyMCEMaker('basic');
$richtext->editor('Description', $temp);
?>



  <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">

  </form>
```

Comment: You can't change a file on a server with Javascript running in a browser - you need server-side code for that. Under some very specific conditions you can change a file on a client with Javascript, but your question is too broad for a specific answer.

Comment: You can't update a file on a server with JavaScript on a client. You could send the new text to the server with an AJAX call, but you will still need some server side code to perform the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**

Javascript is a client side script, you will not be able to change the contents of a file hosted in server using javascript

Comment: You must use PHP or another server side language and save the content after the form has been submitted.

Comment: you can have a look at this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Also what is your architecture? what language are you using in the server side ?