# Update content of html file using JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I asked a similar question yesterday, but did not get a satisfactory answer to my question.

I found a solution. Just not sure what is the mistake in the new program.

In the following program, I first get the contents of the   `announcement.html` and display it in the rich text editor. When the user edits the data in the rich text editor and clicks the submit button, the `announcement.html` needs to be updated, which is done by

```
file_put_contents('./inc/announcement.html',$data);
```

So actually when the submit button is clicked I want to run the `get_editor_content()` function and get the current content in the rich text editor and then send it to the php function and update the html file.

But it is not working. So what is my mistake?

```
<?php
    $temp= file_get_contents('./inc/announcement.html');
    require_once(the_class_name.'TinyMCEMaker.php');
    $richtext = new TinyMCEMaker('basic');
    $richtext->editor('Description', $temp);
?>

<form class="form" id="announcemnet" name="announcemnet" action="Announcemnet.php" method="post" onsubmit="return get_editor_content();">
    <input type="submit" onclick="get_editor_content()">
</form>

<script>
    function get_editor_content() {
        //method1 getting the content of the active editor
        var a = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
    }
</script>

<?php
    $data=$_GET['a'];
    file_put_contents('./inc/announcement.html',$data);
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change content of a HTML file by using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601760/change-content-of-a-html-file-by-using-javascript)

Comment: My program is updated here, So now I know that my button should be  submit button and send the data to php function and then use file_put_contents() to update the html file. I just do not know what is my msitak here.Would you please help me

Comment: you are storing data in variable when button is clicked but where are you updating content of page

Comment: where I say file_put_contents, I am writing the content of that variable which is $data in announcemnet.html file

Comment: You are only putting the contents of the editor into a JavaScript variable, but you are not sending the value of that variable to the server anywhere.

Comment: so when I am definiing my form as action I am saying action="Announcemnet.php", so my assumption was that when the sumit button is clicked then the result of the javascript function called get_editor_content() will be sent to the Announcemnet.php. So am I wrong?how can I make it work like that? so whne the subit button is clicked then the javascript function wil get excecuted and will get the contents of the rich text editor and then the result be sent to the php function and the with file_put_contents they will be written to teh html file.

Answer (score 0):

```
I found the answer.
```

```
 <form action="Home.php" method="post" id="announcement">

    <?php

    $temp= file_get_contents('./path to html file');
    require_once(the_class_name.'TinyMCEMaker.php');
    $richtext = new TinyMCEMaker('basic');
    $richtext->editor('Description', $temp);
    ?>



      <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">

 </form>
```